# Future light cones inside black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities

In Caroll's Spacetime and Geometry, page 227, he says that from the Schwarzschild metric, you can see than from inside a black hole future events all lead to the singularity. He says you can see this because for $r<2GM$, t becomes spacelike and r becomes timelike. I don't understand his reasoning though. Why does r being timelike mean you can only travel towards the singularity?

Comment: It seems like a glorified way of saying that a geodesic travels faster than the speed of light, therefore, not even light, on the edge of the future cone, can increase its distance from the singularity.

Comment: Can you expand on this? I have a rough idea of what you mean, but am unsure.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/why-is-a-black-hole-black/28317#28317 for the restricted case of radial trajectories

Comment: That's a pretty good answer, though I still don't see how you can see this from the Schwarzschild metric.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A good way to understand this is to delve a little more deeply into the meaning of timelike coordinates in flat space, then move up to Schwarzschild space. In flat space, we have the metric

$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2+dy^2+dz^2. $$

Looking at the metric, we can see that only *one* of the spacetime coordinate differentials gets a negative sign ($dt^2$). Looking closer, you can see that this term is the only one that will contribute  negatively to the metric line element, no matter the values of $dx, dy, dz$, or $dt$. In general, you can think of the timelike coordinate as the one that will contribute negatively to the metric line element.

What makes a coordinate timelike? A good way to think about this question is to think about how time differs from the other spacetime coordinates we are used to in flat space. For us, time can *only move forward* (as @elfmotat says, you can't avoid getting older), while we can move freely in the other spacetime coordinate directions. So, for particles, if a coordinate contributes negatively to the line element, then you can *only move forward* in the direction of that coordinate.

To motivate this, I'm just going to appeal to your intuition for lightcones. In Minkowski Space:

[image]

Particles are *forced* to follow timelike geodesics $(ds/d\tau)^2 =-1$ , all of which lie within the future lightcone in the diagram. So the statement that the coordinate that contributes negatively to the metric line element is timelike is kind of a geometrical one. Basically, it confines you to a certain region of spacetime and in so doing only allows forward motion.

Now let's look at the $r, t$ lightcone around a black hole:

[image]
<sub>(source: [asymptotia.com](http://asymptotia.com/wp-images/2008/03/cones3.jpg))</sub>

Once you've crossed the event horizon, all worldlines move backward in $r$. So we say that $r$ becomes timelike while $t$ becomes spacelike.

In the Schwarzschild metric,

$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\Omega
^2, $$
We can see that for $r > 2GM$, the  terms in the parenthesis are positive, and therefore the timelike coordinate is $dt$, since it already has a negative sign outside it. But for $r < 2GM$, the terms in the parenthesis are *negative*, so the time-spacelikeness of $dt, dr$ *flip*, and $dr$ becomes the only coordinate that contributes negatively to the metric line element. What this means physically is that you can *only move forward* in $r$, so in that sense $r$ becomes a timelike coordinate. A bit more pondering should reveal that this mathematical treatment of the problem reproduces the well-known black hole behavior exactly. (Can't go back when you've crossed the event horizon).

Comment: I see, however I don't see why the coordinate that gets a negative sign in the metric necessarily implies you can only move in one direction in that coordinate. On the other hand, can't I apply the same reasoning as you did to the time coordinate to infer that inside a black hole you can freely travel back and forth in time?

Comment: Actually, yes! The time-like and space-like ness of t and r flip, so you actually gain freedom to "move" in coordinate time. But again, remember that the coordinate time t is just a coordinate, and not what you're conventionally used to thinking of as time.

Answer (score 0):

Objects that follow timelike trajectories always have a unique timelike coordinate associated with each point on the trajectory.  This is not true for spacelike trajectories, where a Lorentz transformation can render two points on the path simultaneous.

Hence, an object on a timelike trajectory within the event horizon can only cross a specified radius once along its trajectory.  This means that it *must* either fall all the way inward without stopping or turning back; or it can be completely ejected without stopping or turning back.  These two possibilities are mutually exclusive--if one is possible, the other is not (because time only flows in one direction) for a given system.  The former describes a black hole; the second a "white" hole.

Comment: To add to this, you can't avoid falling toward the singularity any more than you can avoid growing older.

Comment: Since the timelike and spacelike dimensions flip inside a black hole, can you avoid getting older when you cross the event horizon? Even more, can you reverse your aging (just as you can turn around in space)?

Comment: Remember this is just a coordinate singularity, not a physical one.  The geodesics are entirely cobntinuous.  It is merely the coordinates associated with forward progress along those geodesics that change roles.  Even when $r$ is a timelike coordinate instead of $t$, you are still going forward in time.  What's happening is more of a failure of the coordinate to fit the geometry.  There's still a well-defined notion of time (that, as has been pointed out, does *not* always align with $t$).