# How to derive the equation of motion of a test particle free falling into a Schwarzschild blackhole from distance $R$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, free-fall

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/524855) gives the equation for $t(r)$ without the derivation.

I have found the derivation for particles free falling from infinite distance using the Schwarzchild metric and Lagrangian, but I don't know how to apply this to the scenario that a particle free falls from a fixed distance $R$ at rest or with an intial velocity.

---

Below is the results I have got so far.

For simplicity, take $c=G=r_s=1$.

For radial free-fall, we have $d\Omega=0$, so the metric is

$$
ds^2=-(1-\frac1r)dt^2+(1-\frac1r)^{-1}dr^2=-d\tau^2
$$

Let $\dot{x}$ represent $\frac{dx}{d\tau}$, the Lagrangian is
$$
L=\dot{s}^2=-(1-\frac1r)\dot{t}^2+(1-\frac1r)^{-1}\dot{r}^2=-1
$$
As $\frac{d}{d\tau}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{t}})=\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}$, we have conservation of energy $(1-\frac1r)\dot{t}=E$.

In resources I found online, $E$ is set as $1$ for the ease of derivation. Then we have

$$
\dot{r}^2=\frac1r~\Rightarrow~\tau=\frac23(r_0^{3/2}-r^{3/2})
$$

$$
\Rightarrow~d\tau=-r^{1/2}dr
$$
$$
\Rightarrow~dt=(1-\frac1r)^{-1}d\tau=-r^{1/2}(1-\frac1r)^{-1}dr
$$

Integrate both sides to obtain $t=F(r_0)-F(r)$, where
$$
F(r)=\frac23r^{3/2}+2r^{1/2}+ln\frac{r^{1/2}-1}{r^{1/2}+1}.
$$

The solution has nothing to do with the initial position $R$. I guess $E=1$ implies the particle is at rest at inifinity? What should I set $E$ to be if the particle is at rest at distance $R$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772180/123208

Comment: *I don't know how to apply this…* Don’t you solve the same differential equation but with different initial conditions?

Comment: @Ghoster I have updated the post. Specifically, I don't know the relation between energy $E$ and the initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation
$$ (1 - r^{-1}) \dot{t} = E\ , $$
where $E$ is the energy at infinity. But what you want is an initial condition of $E_{\rm shell}=1$, where this represents an object at rest according to some stationary "shell" observer at $r=R$.

The translation between the two comes from the Schwarzschild metric, where we know that since
$$ d\tau_{\rm shell} = dt(1-R^{-1})^{1/2}\ , $$
and thus in the frame of the shell observer
$$E_{\rm shell} = \dot{t}_{\rm shell} = \dot{t}(1 - R^{-1})^{1/2}\ . $$

Substituting for $\dot{t}$ in the initial energy conservation equation, we get
$$(1 - R^{-1}) (1-R^{-1})^{-1/2} E_{\rm shell} = E$$
and thus if $E_{\rm shell}=1$ at $R$, then
$$E = (1 - R^{-1})^{1/2}\ . $$
This can be put back into the first equation to get an expression for $\dot{t}(r)$.
$$\dot{t} = (1 - R^{-1})^{1/2} (1 - r^{-1})^{-1}\ . $$

Comment: Another way to derive $E$ is letting $\dot{r}^2=\frac1r-(1-E^2)$ be $0$ at $R$, which gives $E=(1-\frac1R)^{1/2}$.