# Reconciling Wikipedia formulae for time dilation due to gravity and velocity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, time-dilation, free-fall

Wikipedia "[Time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation)" shows the formula $\sqrt{ 1-v^2-v_e^2-v_r^2.v_e^2/(1-v_e^2) } $
where v is (perhaps) the 3D speed, $v_e$ is the Newtonian escape speed, $v_r$ is the radial speed. 
However "[Proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time)" seems to show the formula $\sqrt{ 1-v_e^2-v_r^2/(1-v_e^2)-v_p^2 }$ where $v_p$ is the speed perpendicular to the gravity vector (i.e. tangential). 
(the speeds are all normalized against c and in coordinate time for a distant stationary observer) 
The second formula seems to work better. For an infalling object with proper speed $\sqrt(r_s/r)$ and [coordinate speed $v_r = (1-r_s/r)\sqrt{(r_s/r)}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583983/what-is-the-general-formula-for-time-dilation-due-to-velocity-and-gravity-togeth/584004#584004) (per @John Rennie), the time dilation drops to zero at the event horizon, $r=r_s$. For an object in circular orbit with proper speed $\sqrt{(r_s/2r)/(1-r_s/r)}$ and coordinate speed $v_p = \sqrt(r_s/2r)$ [Raine & Thomas p.36], the time dilation drops to zero at $r = (3/2)r_s$.  
I'd appreciate any help getting this straight.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Just enclose all formulas with a dollar sign and put a backlash in front of every "sqrt" for a try.

Comment: And a _ for a subscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turns out to be just algebra.  "$v$" is indeed the 3D speed which can be expressed in terms of the radial and tangential (perpendicular to field) speeds: $v^2 = v_r^2 + v_p^2$.
So, starting with the first expression 
$\;\;\;\sqrt{ 1-v^2-v_e^2-v_r^2.v_e^2/(1-v_e^2) }$ 
= $\sqrt{ 1-v_r^2 -v_p^2-v_e^2-v_r^2.v_e^2/(1-v_e^2) }$ 
= $\sqrt{ 1 - v_p^2-v_e^2-v_r^2-v_r^2.v_e^2/(1-v_e^2) }$ 
= $\sqrt{ 1 - v_p^2-v_e^2-v_r^2(1+v_e^2/(1-v_e^2))}$ 
= $\sqrt{ 1 - v_p^2-v_e^2-v_r^2/(1-v_e^2)}$ 
= $\sqrt{ 1 -v_e^2-v_r^2/(1-v_e^2) - v_p^2}$ 
which is the second expression