# Can Schwarzschild black holes evaporate?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

I recently saw [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101619/photons-straight-into-black-hole), and came across a claim from Anixx that a Schwarzschild black hole cannot evaporate because it is static:

> @HDE 226868 Schwartzshield solution is a static one, which does not change with time.

Yet [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Emission_process) there exists a detailed derivation of how a Schwarzschild black hole can emit Hawking radiation.

Is Wikipedia right? Can Schwarzschild black holes evaporate?

Comment: Showing that the Schwarzschild black hole will be emitting Hawking radiation at any given moment (using [semi-classical gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiclassical_gravity) which is an approach to modeling quantum fields on curved spacetime, without treating the spacetime itself in a quantum way as would need to be done in a true theory of quantum gravity) is not the same as showing that its event horizon actually shrinks over time, I would think.

Comment: The Schwarzschild metric is static by definition. If the metric changes over time then it's not the Schwarzschild metric. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the answer is too exciting. The Schwarzschild solution is a static solution to the Einstein field equations. The Einstein field equations alone don't take into account quantum effects. Taking quantum effects into account will give you a modification of the solution, and the result that the Schwarzschild 'solution' is no longer static (and so could hardly be called a 'solution' any more).

Comment: Doing a little searching, it seems that the spacetime of an evaporating black hole is often modeled in general relativity using a [Vaidya metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaidya_metric) but having it absorb negative mass/energy instead of positive, for example p. 4 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0509048v2) says "In the dynamical horizon equation, if black hole absorbs negative energy, black hole radius decreases."