# At what rate does a photon blue shift as it falls toward a black hole and red shift as time slows close to a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation, redshift

Perhaps I am thinking about this incorrectly when a photon arrives at an event horizon, from an observers perspective time has essentially stopped for it and the photon has red shifted completely. Before redshifting, the photon would have blue-shifted due to gravity. I cannot think of how to calculate this and I am hoping someone could shed some light on this.

Also, what happens to the energy of the photon since it is redshifted completely?

Comment: Have  look at the the answers here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101619/photons-straight-into-black-hole

Comment: Why do you say the photon blueshufts? For which observer?

Comment: "*Also, what happens to the energy of the photon since it is redshifted completely?*"  -The energy of the BH is $E=Mc^2$. Do you think it includes the energy of the infalling photon?