# Are there any processes taking place in a black hole that generate light or other EM radiation? What happens with that radiation?

Tags: black-holes

Are there any processes (such as fusion or fission) taking place in a black hole that generate light or other EM radiation? What happens with that radiation? Does it start "flying" out and then, due to the gravity, make a U-turn and return to the black hole?

Comment: Do you mean inside the event horizon? Or on the accretion disc?

Comment: I mean in the solid body of the black hole so inside the event horizon, but the event horizon is far away for the actual body, isn't it? In the core, or between the core and the surface, of the black hole. Similar to how a regular star fusions matter in its body.

Comment: Does a black hole have a solid body?

Comment: Nothing can escape the event horizon by definition. What happens inside, stays inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a black hole black?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/why-is-a-black-hole-black)

Comment: Then we have no way of knowing. I don't know if something has been theorized on the matter, but it couldn't be proven or disproven because we can't have any kind of information from inside the black hole. Information needs something to "hitchhike" and since not even light can come out of it, we can't check what's on the inside.

Comment: Yes I understand that it is not detectable. I was looking for some theoretical or hypothetical answer.

Comment: @my2cts Good question. You should ask it in a separate question.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason why processes leading to the emission of light would not work inside the event horizon of the black hole. Nothing should change about the physics of what is going on until nearing the central "singularity".

Of course we cannot know for sure, because all the light emitted from inside the event horizon ends up at the singularity too and cannot be observed from outside the event horizon.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Are there any processes (such as fusion or fission)

and aldo in  a comment of yours:

> I mean in the solid body of the black hole so inside the event horizon, but the event horizon is far away for the actual body, isn't it? In the core, or between the core and the surface, of the black hole. Similar to how a regular star fusions matter in its body

Lets keep things clear.

A black hole in classical relativity is a singularity, i.e. a point in the simplest case, and according to the theory all the mass ends up on this one point.

Fusion and fission happen at the quantum mechanical level.

Now  in the cosmological model of the [Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), which has a singularity at the origin,  they introduced effective quantization of gravity in order to explain discrepancies in distribution observed, with the predictions of a point singularity at the origin of the universe. This introduced a fuzzy quantum mechanical region where the singularity was, and then also an inflation period so that the data/observations could be fitted.

In this quantum mechanical region there are no nuclei and such, because the energy is too high for constituent particles. Particular quantum particles called inflatons have been introduced to describe the observations .

It is not far fetched to expect that with an effective quantum mechanical model the singularity of the black hole should be also expanded with some quantum particles, but these will not be nuclei, as the energies will be too high for binding. Maybe a quark gluon soup?